# trouble with async task

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project which uses firebase database and at this time I'm trying to read async data from my base using this piece of code:

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        let ref1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chats")
        let curUserUid = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
        myGroup.enter()
        ref1.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChildren() {
                let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                for elem in postDict {
                    let valuesDict = elem.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                    for kv in valuesDict {

                        if kv.key == "name" && kv.value.contains(curUserUid) {
                            MainUsersList.currentChats.append(elem.key)
                            print(elem.key)
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
           myGroup.leave()
        })
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            //self.loadLastMsgs()
            self.ShowVC()
        })
```

And ShowVC method:

```
let st = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
let anotherVC = st.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "messagesVC")
self.present(anotherVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
print("showVC")
```

And in another VC I have this code in viewDidLoad:

```
print("!!!!!!!")
print(MainUsersList.currentChats.count)
```

When I perform a button click, where first piece of code is written, i get this in console:

> !!!!!!!
>
> 0
>
> y2MTmBq8o0QF9yxcSBCOpI1DZku2-DnYqmHW2umWaWN54buhtGrXEToW2  //elem.key
>
> showVC
>
> !!!!!!!
>
> 1

So, my question is WHY ShowVC performing before async task ends and WHY it performs twice (I don't have another code with print(!!!!!!!))? Thanks in advance!
P.S. and I don't have self.ShowVC() code written elsewhere for sure

Comment: Learn to understand how asynchronous tasks work. In your case the group is not needed at all. Just replace `myGroup.leave()` with `self.ShowVC()` and delete all other DispatchGroup related code. *Don't ask, tell !*

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong. I just had triggered segue to my second VC, so that my code performed twice. All other code is correct)